# What is the process to install cyanogenmod to a galaxy tab 10.1?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

I am new to this flashing business for the Android tablets. I did some of those flashing on a PanDigital tablet previously, but it's been a while. My tablet is the standard 32G WiFi tablet, and it's been rooted. How can I get the cyanogenmod ROM installed, and how does this fastboot thing work ? I also have the recovery.img file.

BTW: How can I backup the existing ROM, so I can restore if something goes wrong ?

Thanks :-)

Comment: I dont think CM is supported on the SGS Tab 10 yet. [Here](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/devices) is a list of supported devices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a supported device, then this should basically be the process as it is the same for every supported device I have experienced.

1. Put the cyanogenmod update zip file on the device sdcard (or internal storage)
2. Also put the google apps update package that corresponds to the CM version on the sdcard
3. Boot the device in to recovery mode
4. You can create a backup in the Recovery image (probably clockworkMod recovery)
5. clear the cache and wipe the data
6. install zip from sdcard (selecting the cyanogenmod zip)
7. install zip from sdcard (selecting the google apps zip)
8. reboot the device.

If you have ROM Manager, a lot of this process may even be easier. With ROM Manager, which can also install ClockWorkMod Recovery if it is supported on the device, you can download CyanogenMod, the google apps package, clear the cache and user data, and perform the backup. It will then reboot the device and perform all those steps.

Now, as I said, I am not 100% sure that CM is supported on this device, so there may be other steps required to get an unofficial version working on the device. With that said, Samsung devices are usually pretty easy to get back to the Stock version if something goes wrong (soft brick). It is pretty hard to brick these devices, I have had a couple scares, but I have always been able to revert back to original stock ROM by using ODIN.

Comment: I got the Cyanogenmod file for my tablet. Everything I read says it runs just fine, except for the camera. Wherer can I find the Google apps update file ? Is this the file named recovery.img. What else do i need to get this modded Android loaded on my tablet ? I have both a Linux and a Windows station, although I'd rather stay with Linux.

Comment: you shouldnt need a PC at all except may to transfer the zip to the device. do not extract the zip, the Recovery will process the zip file. The google apps can be found at http://goo-inside.me

Comment: SO if I can transfer the files via the card reader to /sdcard on the device, that should be enough ? And the files are the cyanogem signed .md5 file, the .bin file and the google apps other zip files ?

Comment: the files are not already in a zip file? the zip is what you need to transfer to the device. not the files IN the zip.

Comment: I was not sure which file to retrieve to get the Google apps. I understand that I then only have to put both zip files in /sdcard and install them. I assume I install cyanogenmod then google apps (once I figure out the file name to download). What APK should I install to be able to backup the image for an eventual recovery ? I know. I have many questions.