# How do I install cyanogenmod on a Galaxy Tab 3 (7.0)?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-tab-3-7

For Christmas I got a Galaxy Tab 3 (7in, SM-T110) for the wee ones to play with. I want to secure it as much as possible so they cannot accidentally buy stuff or get tracked or whatever. So I thought I'd install Cyanogenmod.

However, the device is not officially supported. From what I understand, I can still install Cyanogenmod on the device, it's just a bit more complicated. Obviously, it is possible, because there's "tutorials" out there about how to do it by people who have successfully done so. Never having done any of this, though. I got lost pretty soon among instructions on rooting, using ODIN, CWM, TWRP, ROM managers, and whatnot. *Sigh.*

So what do I need to do in order to install Cyanogenmod? I suppose I need to root the device? Do I need a ROM manager? Or is it advisable? What do I need ODIN for? Do I need ODIN? What I need is *1)* a thorough explanation what all of these buzzwords mean and what they are good for, and *2)* a step-by-step for dummies for how to put them together.

*Note: I have seen [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/20041/13431) (which assumes the device to be supported) and [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/62986/13431) (which assumes too much knowledge).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the device is not supported officially, you may be able to find an unofficial build for the device. If you find that, then the [first answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20036/what-is-the-process-to-install-cyanogenmod-to-a-galaxy-tab-10-1/20041#20041) you linked to is your instructions, as installing CM on any device basically requires the same steps.

If there is not even an unofficial build, then I do not recommend you install any build of CM on your device. All you are likely to do is 'soft brick' the device. ROMs have to be built specifically for the hardware, and hardware can differ even between variants of the exact same device. Like a T-mobile version versus AT&T version.

Rooting the device will not get you any closer to installing cyanogenmod. You will need a custom recovery. ODIN is usually used to install Samsung based ROMs, so you shouldn't need to use ODIN. But, this really all depends on if you have found an Unofficial build of CyanogenMod for the SM-T110. Without that, your only other option is to build an unofficial build yourself, that does require a lot of knowledge of how linux, android, and build systems, etc. work.

On the cyanogenmod forums there is [a request to add support for the device](http://forum.cyanogenmod.org/topic/92432-samsung-galaxy-tab-3-lite-wifi-sm-t110/).

Comment: Thanks! Would [this](http://www.androidtablets.net/threads/cyanogenmod-for-samsung-galaxy-tab-3-variants.64133/) qualify as a link to an "unofficial build"?

Comment: Looks like that is for the SM-210, which probably won't work for the SM-110.

Comment: Thanks. The link leads to a page that also lists [110](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?w=files&flid=13411). However, my problem is that, while I am able to find bits and pieces that might be needed for doing this, I lack the overview of how this all fits together.

Comment: So the link you sent for the 110 is for ClockworkMod which is the custom recovery. That would be "step 1" of what you need. [This](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2755532) is a better source, but just at my quick glance, I do not see even an unofficial CM build for your device.

Answer (score 1):

Installing Cyanogen Mod means you are installing a ROM that is bulit on Cyanogen.
So basically installing any of ROM(Cyanogen built) will give you Cynaogen on your phone.

Installing these ROM require the following steps:

1.You need to **ROOT** your phone/tab (Caution:ROOT voids warranty)

2.Install **recovery** (Samsung has inbuilt) (Caution:Soft brick in case you don't follow proper steps)
    Follow the link to root and recovery :
    http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2437219

3.Install ROM using recovery
  You can find varoius ROMs and information related to development on XDA forum.
  Visit the link for Galaxy Tab 3:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-tab-3/development-7

Comment: You do not need root to install cyanogenmod. you need a custom recovery, which you can flash if you have an unlocked bootloader. An unlocked bootloader is not the same as root. Usually to get past the unlocked bootloader they make use of an exploit, and usually the same exploit is used to root the device, but they are not the same.